# $("#frm_data")[0].reset(); Can not clear input type=file value after ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to try reset form value on ajax success response. everything was clear instant of input type="file".

```
<form  id="frm_data" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Logo: </label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
       <input type="file" name="logo" id="logo" class="styled"/>
       <br>  <br>  
   </div>
   <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">description:</label>
   <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea rows="5" cols="5" name="desc" id="desc" class="form-control"></textarea>
   </div>
</form>
```

## Ajax Response

```
success: function(response)
    {
        $("#desc").cleditor()[0].clear();
        $("#btnSubmit").attr('value', 'Add');
        $("#frm_data")[0].reset();

    }
```

[image: i see like this]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if file inputs work with reset(), but you can try assigning an empty value like so:

```
 $("#frm_data").find('[type=file]').val('');
```

Comment: Then your problem is not related to clearing the input anymore. Hard to tell what it is without seeing exactly what happens.

Comment: see the question again

Comment: It seems that you have an additional script that populates some span elements with the file chosen. Maybe you can fix this by also triggering the "change" event after you clear the input. Like so: `$("#frm_data").find('[type=file]').val('').trigger('change');`

Comment: its can be reload page. i want without reload instantly

Comment: It shouldn't reload your page, unless you have an error on your code when submitting the form. Check your console for that.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Comment: You most probably have a syntax error. Like a missing character or an extra one. I can't help you with that, but I have updated the jsfiddle with the correct line, so make sure your code looks similar. https://jsfiddle.net/sq9s8w19/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#logo').val('');
```

It will clear your input type file.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:
`$("#frm_data").find('[type=file]').val('').trigger('change');`